# Agregar un elemento a un array por cada iteracion de un foreach

Tags: php, array

tengo un problema con una iteracion de bucle foreach, el problema es que consulta la informacion desde una API, la cual me devuelve una lista de productos en XML y cuando la recibo la convierto a JSON y la almaceno en un array, si imprimo mi resultado me los va mostrando asi:

> Array ( [servicio] => Acuario Inbursa CDMX [producto] => Acuario CDMX
> 1 Entrada [idServicio] => 899 [idProducto] => 6443 [idCatTipoServicio]
> => 11 [tipoFront] => 1 [hasDigitoVerificador] => false [precio] => 215.0 [showAyuda] => false [tipoReferencia] => a )
>
> Array ( [servicio] => Acuario Inbursa CDMX [producto] => Acuario CDMX
> 2 Entradas [idServicio] => 899 [idProducto] => 6448
> [idCatTipoServicio] => 11 [tipoFront] => 1 [hasDigitoVerificador] =>
> false [precio] => 430.0 [showAyuda] => false [tipoReferencia] => a )
>
> Array ( [servicio] => Acuario Inbursa CDMX [producto] => Acuario CDMX
> 4 Entradas [idServicio] => 899 [idProducto] => 6451
> [idCatTipoServicio] => 11 [tipoFront] => 1 [hasDigitoVerificador] =>
> false [precio] => 860.0 [showAyuda] => false [tipoReferencia] => a )

Ahora mi duda es como puedo almacenar esa informacion en un nuevo array para despues enviarla a una base de datos mi idea es que quede asi **array("servicio", "Acuario", "idServicio", "654");**

Como el array trae varios arreglos dentro de si lo recorro de la siguiente forma:

```
if (is_array($array) || is_object($array)){
    foreach ($array['PRODUCTOS'] as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value) || is_object($value)) {
            foreach ($value as $key => $value) {
                if (is_array($value) || is_object($value)) {
                    foreach ($value as $key => $value) {
                        if (is_array($value) || is_object($value)) {
                            foreach ($value as $row) {
                                print_r($value);
                                echo "<br>";
                                break;
                            }
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Pero ahora no se como guardarlo para poder enviarlo a una base de datos.

Comment: no me queda claro que datos requieres dejar en tu nuevo arreglo, podrías dar un poco mas de detalles, como por ejemplo que seria "servicio" es un el key o el value

Comment: Esto no te esta devolviendo un arreglo, te esta devolviendo un string muy largo de los elementos relacionados `$key` y `$value` separados por un `' => '`; que no es lo mismo que un arreglo. Primero, tu tarea es obtener un arreglo en el formato correcto `$array = [ '$key' => '$value' ]` y luego se vera el paso de insertarlo en la base de datos.

Comment: @ajsoler Tienes razon, ya lo corregi y actualice el codigo, ya me devuelve un array, ahora quiero saber como guardarlo en la bd

Comment: @ajsoler ya actualice el codigo

Comment: En cada _foreach_ estás redefiniendo `$key` y `$value`, ¿seguro que funciona?

Comment: Puedes acceder a cada dato que te interese usando su clave. Parece que te interesa solamente `servicio` y `idServicio`, entonces, puedes ir directamente a por los valores en esas claves. Sería algo así: `foreach ($elArray as $k=>$v) { $newArray[$k]["servicio"]=$v["servicio"]; $newArray[$k]["idServicio"]=$v["idServicio"]; }` Así tendrás en `$newArray` los datos que te interesan en cada índice respectivo. Tienes que hacerlo en el nivel preciso donde se encuentren los datos, sin tantas historias de for, dentro de for, dentro de for.

Answer (score 0):

Vine a intentar darte una mano. Según entiendo estas almacenando el objeto JSON en un array.

Antes que nada te recomiendo que lo trabajes como objeto. Ya que lo que querés hacer es acceder a las propiedades del mismo y guardar sus valores en variables para después insertarlos en arreglos ordenados.
(Yo te recomiendo en asociativos. Pero basandome en el ejemplo que me diste es un array ordenado).

Bien, empezamos obteniendo el XML.

```
function api(){
$link = #URL de tu API;
$contenido = file_get_contents($link);
$json = json_decode($contenido);
return $json;
#Notese como prefiero trabajarlo como objeto al no usar el segundo parametro de json_decode(); [true]
}
```

Una vez obtenida la API y guardada en la variable $json procederemos a llamar a nuestra funcion asignandole una variable (Lugar donde se guardará el `return` de $json)

```
$informacion = api();
```

Bien, solo empezamos a acceder a las propiedades del objeto con el bucle `foreach` y el operador `->` Quedandonos una cosa asi:

```
foreach($informacion as $puntero => $valor){
 $servicio = $valor->servicio;
 $producto = $valor->producto;
 /*
Y asi sucesivamente con el objeto. Pero tene en cuenta que se almacena la ultima variable que recorrio.
*/ 
}
#Luego almacenas en array ordenado:
$mi_array = [
    $servicio, 
    $producto
];
```

Inicias conexion a base de datos:

```
$servername = 'localhost';
$serveruser = 'usuario';
$serverpassword = 'password';
$serverdatabase = 'basededatos';
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $serveruser, $serverpassword, $serverdatabase);
```

Y luego insertas usando el codigo del noble usuario que respondio arriba mio.

Te recomiendo que sigamos esto en el chat para que puedas enviar como se muestra el objeto sin convertir a Array para de esa forma no violar el espacio de StackOverflow.